# How to mirror maven repositories

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I am working on a multimodule project in which I have Spring boot dependency configured in parent project. In one of child project project I have plugin dependency which is not present on public repo. Which should download from custom link for  that i am using custom settings.xml file to mirror it.

```
<mirror>
  <id>id</id>
  <url>url</url>
  <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
</mirror>
```

If I do like this error for my plugin dependency resolves, but it is giving error for spring-boot dependency.
     `could not transfer dependency` and if i remove it is giving error for my dependency.
I also tried

```
<mirror>
  <id>id</id>
  <url>url</url>
  <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
</mirror>
<mirror>
  <id>id1</id>
  <url>public maven repo link</url>
  <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
</mirror>
```

It is giving same error. I want both spring and my dependency will work. How can I do that. Is am i doing wrong or suggest something that would solve my problem.
Any help would be appreciated. Could any one help!

Comment: Install a repository manager and install your non public dependency into that repository manager and the problem is solved....

Comment: I already have the repository manager url. But if i use that is is giving error for spring dependencies